# Can't open a NetCDF-4 classic file in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I am new to R. My code is

```
> library(ncdf4)
> ncdf="/Datasets/noaa.ersst.v5/sst.mnmean.nc"
> ncin <- nc_open(ncdf)
Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: HDF error
Error in nc_open(ncdf) : 
  Error in nc_open trying to open file /Datasets/noaa.ersst.v5/sst.mnmean.nc
```

But

```
 ncdump -kh /Datasets/noaa.ersst.v5/sst.mnmean.nc 
 netCDF-4 classic model
```

and

```
ncdump -h /Datasets/noaa.ersst.v5/sst.mnmean.nc
```

looks fine. It can be plotted in pretty much all of our applications. Any ideas?

On my Mac:
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"

I downloaded ncdf4 library and installed it.

Comment: Probably can't help without access to the data file. Only other advice is to update R to version 4 and make sure you have the latest package versions. Is the netcdf from:  https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.noaa.ersst.v5.html

Comment: If what you have is the file in https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/noaa.ersst.v5/sst.mnmean.nc then this works for me with ncdf4 package version 1.17 in R 4.1.1 on Linux.